# Publishing site vs. team site

Tags: 2010, publishing-site

We're trying to figure out the advantages/disadvantages of using Team Site or Publishing Site. The publishing site enables setting page titles more easily, along with scheduling of content, etc. However, team site's page layouts better suit our needs. We'll have a few people rolling out content for intranet departments. Documents will be shared as well.

- In your experience, how do you determine which one to do with?
- Also, can we go with a team site and enable publishing on it? What would we lose if we take this route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally go with the template that comes closest to my needs, and activate additional features on that one. In your case, I would go with the team-site and activate the publishing features on it. Please note that the landing page of your team-site will be replaced by the standard publishing site, which will have the same look and feel as when you create a publishing site.

Isn't it a possibility for you to create the team site, enable the publishing features, change its page layout and copy the webparts that you need to the landing page?

Comment: Thanks, Bas. We've created the team site but can't get the old team site layouts to show when creating pages.

Comment: Alex, that is because teamsites use "webpartpages" as layout, while publishing portals use the publishing page layouts. These are different kind of pages. Publishing pages reside in the "pages" directory, while the landing page of a teamsite is in the root (if I remember correctly). Apart from that, webpartpages can reside in any kind of document library.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a tough call but it really depends on what features you want on the site, and even then, like @Bas stated, you can enable or disable features that are or are not part of the site definition by default.  This is very much a case, of choosing which ever suits you better.

Although, it was written for 2007, it is still relevant.

http://mindsharpblogs.com/penny/archive/2007/09/28/2973.html

MS articles
Clarifications: Collaboration vs. Publishing
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mossbiz/archive/2009/06/23/clarifications-collaboration-vs-publishing.aspx

Technet Best Practice sites

Publishing: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850698.aspx

Team Sites: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850694.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Jesus. I've noticed that when you add the publishing to a team site and create a page, the team site page layouts are gone; you now have the publishing layouts. Any way to import/recreate a two-column page layout that team site offers. It's nothing fancy, but just makes life easier. Or should we just create a custom page layout for that?